# retrieving a row from sqlite database

Tags: android-sqlite

I implemented a list whose items are gotten from a database, and when I click on an item on the next page I want it to show me the information about that item that is stored in one of the database rows. But a `no such :name` problem occurs.

My code to retrieve the row is :

```
public Cursor getPerson(String name) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor mCursor =
    db.query(true, Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, Constants.PERSON_NAME + "=" + name, null, null,null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

My code for clicking on the item is :

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    db.open();
    try{
        Cursor c=db.getPerson(mAdapter.getItem(position));
        p.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.PERSON_NAME)));
        p.setAccount(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.ACCOUNT)));
        if(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.TYPE))>0)
            p.setType(true);
        else
            p.setType(false);
        Intent intent =new Intent(Main.this, Person_page.class);
        intent.putExtra("com.pooya.dongali.Main", p);
        startActivity(intent);
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.close();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.query(true, Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, Constants.PERSON_NAME + "=?", new String[]{name}, null,null, null, null);`